# How do I reset ImageView memory in Android?

Tags: android, image, memory-leaks, bitmap, out-of-memory

My app is a question and answer type thing. So I load specific string into an activity and that activity display it. My problem is that when I change to a new question for example q1 -> q2, it will load a another string and also picture. But this picture stay in the memory after I change it to s2 -> s3 and thus leading to run out of memory. How do I reset the ImageView so it doesn't stay in the memory?
I'm pretty new to android.

The code is roughly like this.

```
    public void getdata(){
        imageView.setImageResource(0);
        switch (data){
            case 1;
            row1.setText(qt1r1);
            row2.setText(qt1r2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.q1);
            break;
            case 2;
            row1.setText(qt2r1);
            row2.setText(qt2r2);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.q2);
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How did you set an image in ImageView?

Comment: please share code, from current information its not clear what you are doing which leads to out of memory error

Comment: and the your condition to set different images !

Comment: you can try using an image parsing library like Picasso and Glide, it will automatically handle the resource and memory management. they also have options to load smaller thumbnail versions of the image. Alternatively, you can try reducing the size of your  image files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's depend on your resources resolutions.Here is a good library.You can fix your problem like this

```
Glide.with(fragment)
.load(R.drawable.resource_id)
.into(imageView);
```

For assets, you can construct an asset uri:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
.load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/assetName"))
.into(imageView);
```

[Here is a library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: i dnt know why your answering something which not belongs to question bcz first time u put answer set 0 on image view which already showing in question now ur showing glide with assets (showing) but he is using resource file . So no sense of answer..

Comment: In my case set 0 working correctly ,but I hope problem is image resources and Glide is a best library to work large images

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know such library existed.